How to resolve ESLint config in React application?
When I start creating a new React app and when it is finished it show me this error:
Compiled with problems:

ERROR
[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\cheikh verhane\documents\projects\react\ecommerce\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\cheikh verhane\Documents\Projects\react\ecommerce\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

How can I fix it?
I tried to remove all node_modules and package-lock.json then I run this command npm install

you can check this steps to fix this problem
Check and clean package.json: Ensure there are no conflicting versions of ESLint or eslint-config-react-app.
Remove node_modules and lock files: You already tried this step, but let's ensure all caches are cleared properly.
Reinstall dependencies: Install dependencies again after cleaning up.
Override ESLint configuration if needed: Sometimes, adding or modifying .eslintrc or eslintConfig in package.json might resolve the issue.
